# Use model attribute as parameter on sequelize operator

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize v6 on my nodejs/express application. I am struggling to use an attribute of my model in the where clause of my findAll query.

What I want to achieve in SQL:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable
WHERE field2 != field3
```

what i have in my javascript:

```
const resultArray = myTable.findAll({
     attributes: [
         "field1",
         "field2",
         "field3",],
     where: {
        field2: { [Op.ne]: {field3}},
     })
```

What I am after is the right context to reference field3 in the [Op.ne] parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Sequelize.col` to indicate a reference to a column for Sequelize:

```js
const resultArray = myTable.findAll({
     attributes: [
         "field1",
         "field2",
         "field3",],
     where: {
        field2: { [Op.ne]: Sequelize.col('field3') },
     })
```